# FastAPI and "While True" process

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi

I have some function that is doing stuff in while True (for example just print a str):

```
class LoopHandler(metaclass=Singleton):

    def start_loop(self, phrase: str):

        while True:
            print(phrase)
            time.sleep(1)
```

And I have a simple FastAPI server running in parallel:

```
class APIServer(uvicorn.Server):
    def install_signal_handlers(self):
        pass

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def run_in_thread(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        thread.start()
        try:
            while not self.started:
                time.sleep(1e-3)
            yield
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.should_exit = True
            thread.join()
```

And it works fine, text prints, API works.
But the task is to "restart" loop when specific API method is called. Something like this:

```
@app.get("/get")
async def get():
    response = {'response': 'response'}
    # restart loop here with LoopHandler().start_loop('another Text')
    return response
```

Thanks for any advice!

My main():

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = uvicorn.Config("api_view:app", log_level="debug")
    server = APIServer(config=config)
    with server.run_in_thread():
        LoopHandler().start_loop('Text')
```

**ADD**:

When I call `LoopHandler` from API, It begin new thread and new LoopHandler instance in it. So, if I add flag, like this:

```
class LoopHandler(metaclass=Singleton):

def __init__(self, done: bool = False):
    self.done = done

def start_loop(self, phrase: str):

    while not self.done:
        print(phrase)
        time.sleep(1)
```

My console looks like this:

```
Text
another Text
Text
another Text
Text
```

Comment: One possibility is to add a variable `done` to `LoopHandler` initialized to `False` in the `__init__` method.  `while True:` becomes `while not done:` and your restart method simply sets `done` to True.  You're setting up your loop handler to do polling.

Comment: @FrankYellin, thanks, it works but there is a problem. My stdout: another Text
Text
another Text
Text
another Text
Text. It initiates a new instance of LoopHandler (that is Singleton, btw) for some reason....